# How to get minimum value from a set of values returned by SELECT query?

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I have written a SELECT query, which will return a set of values, for ex.,

The following one is the actual table -

[image]

```
select data from tab1 where id <5; // This statement returns me the following table
```

[image]

I am trying to get the minimum value of the resultant table. I have tried the following query for that -

```
select MIN(select data from tab1 where id<5);
```

SQLite Browser says, there is an error in the select statement. My doubt is, whether we can give a select statement directly into an aggregate function like MIN()? If not, can you please suggest me a better way to do this task?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this way:

```
select MIN(data) 
from tab1 where id<5;
```

Comment: Oh, Thank you very much @Parado, the code is working now. Actually what I have posted here is an example. But my actual query is very big. So I got confused with that. I have applied your concept, and its working now.